# angularjs model doesnt get updated on select change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jquery-chosen

I am trying to integrate angularjs and jquery chosen plugin, everything works fine but when changed the model doesnt get updated can some one tell me how to go about doing this, There is a video on youtube that explains the same but I dont have access to youtube, any help will be highly appreciated

This is my html code:

```
<select id="categories" data-placeholder="Select Categories" 
    chosen="categories" ng-model="categoriesSelected" multiple="" 
    ng-options="category.name for category in categories"></select>
<div ng-repeat="category in categoriesSelected">{{category.name}}</div>
```

This is the angular code:

```
app.directive('chosen', function()
{
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attr)
        {
            console.log(attr);

            $("#" + attr.id).chosen();

            scope.$watch(attr.chosen, function(oldVal, newVal)
            {
                $("#" + attr.id).trigger('chosen:updated');
            });

            scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function()
            {
                $("#" + attr.id).trigger('chosen:updated');
            });

        }
    };
})

app.controller("workbenchController", function($scope, $http, workbenchService)
{
    $scope.categories = [];
    $scope.categoriesSelected = [];
    workbenchService.categoriesList().then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.categories = data;
    })
}
```

Comment: did you try ng-change in the select input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be that jquery plugins make DOM modifications after the angular application has been compiled, that means the angular app will not be able to use the element as part of the app (no ng-model, ng-show, etc for that element), for that reason you must try not use jquery plugins but angular directives that way the directive will compile along side the app and youll get everything working as expected.

A better aproach for your problem will be use the `ui-select` directive that is an angular native select box that works just as selectize, chosen or select2, more info and download [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

and a working plunker example [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your controller:

```
app.controller("workbenchController", function($scope, $http, workbenchService)
{
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.categories = [];
    $scope.data.categoriesSelected = [];

    workbenchService.data.categoriesList().then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.data.categories = data;
    })
}
```

So you Html must point to:

```
<select id="categories" data-placeholder="Select Categories" 
    chosen="categories" ng-model="data.categoriesSelected" multiple="" 
    ng-options="category.name for category in categories"></select>
<div ng-repeat="category in data.categoriesSelected">{{category.name}}</div>
```

read this, please: [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)